# JavaScript- validation data in a set of unlimited combobox

Tags: javascript, validation, combobox

I've got a problem validating data in a set of select comboboxes. In this case, there is a set of unlimited combo boxes with integer values. How can I validate the values of these comboboxes in javascript?  For example, when I select a value1 in combobox 1, the combobox 2 will display values bigger than value1, and when I select value2 in combobox2, the combobox3 only display values bigger than value2, etc.

How can I best accomplish this?

Comment: It would help if you include the code you've tried so far so people answering can see your thought process and something tangible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow. Please visit http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: until now I have no idea about this. At first, i thought I will use getElementById() to get an array list of values in combobox2, then re-write the second combobox with values bigger than value selected in combobox1, but I don't know how to check the next value in other combobox3, combobox4... because this set of combobox is unknown quantity and their id is unable to control as well